# Forward declare a struct in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, forward, declare

I'm creating a protocol, and one of the parameters to a method I'm defining is a `CMTime*`. I would like to forward declare `CMTime` as opposed to including it. However, I've tried `@class CMTime` and it complains that it is redefined elsewhere as a different type of symbol. Documentation says it's a struct. I've tried forward declaring it as

```
struct CMTime;
```

but it still is complaining that it doesn't know what it is.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is declared using an anonymous struct. This means you either have to copy the entire declaration (and hope it never changes), or just include the header.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw copying it isn't good (chances are, both declarations will end up in the same TU).other than that, I think that qualifies as a specific answer, considering how `CMTime`'s been declared.

Comment: @Justin I only suggested it because he said he wasn't going to include the header, but now that I think about it, he was getting an error that it had already been defined when trying to create a class, which would suggest the header was already included. If someone can explain that, I might post it as an answer.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw presumably, it was because the OP forgot or omitted the `struct` tag when used. `void foo(CMTime*)` vs. `void foo(struct CMTime*)`.

Comment: You should accept justin's answer.

Answer (score 18):

A source compiled as ObjC has the same rules as C in this regard.

A source compiled as ObjC++ has the same rules as C++ in this regard.

`@class MONClass;` is a forward declaration of an ObjC type. Do not use it for structs.

`struct t_mon_struct;` is a forward declaration of a *named* C or C++ struct. Do not use it for ObjC types. Technically, the compiler allows you to also forward declare a C++ class as a struct (provided of course the class is also declared in the global namespace).

Thus, the root of the semantics all boil down to C (assuming this is an ObjC translation). I'll stop mentioning ObjC and C++ now.

There are some common sources of complexity here:

- the struct namespace
- the struct's declaration
- avoiding multiple definitions of labels

`struct t_mon_struct;` is a forward declaration of a tagged struct. Specifically, that is whose name exists in the struct namespace.

a tagged struct which exists in the struct namespace:

```
struct t_mon_struct { int a; };
```

an anonymous struct with a typedef in the global namespace:

```
typedef struct { int a; } t_mon_struct;
```

a tagged struct with a typedef in the global namespace:

```
typedef struct t_mon_struct { int a; } t_mon_struct;
```

`CMTime` is declared as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    CMTimeValue    value;
    CMTimeScale    timescale;
    CMTimeFlags    flags;
    CMTimeEpoch    epoch;
} CMTime;
```

Specifically, the global typedef label `CMTime` is bound to an anonymous struct in the struct namespace, and may not be referenced unless its declaration is visible.

Had `CMTime` been declared:

```
typedef struct CMTime
{
    CMTimeValue    value;
    CMTimeScale    timescale;
    CMTimeFlags    flags;
    CMTimeEpoch    epoch;
} CMTime;
```

then you could have gotten by using a forward declaration `struct CMTime`:

```
struct CMTime;
void foo(struct CMTime*);
```

Since it wasn't declared that way, you'll need to `#include` its declaration, or devise a workaround.

The complications worsen when the the struct's typedef is distinct from its tag. You can't bind to or redeclare a typedef (in C). However, you can sneak around it by using the name in the struct namespace -- which some library authors consider as being private.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding `typedef` before the struct does the trick for me.

```
typedef struct CMTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the files which have the forward declaration to know about the contents of the struct, they need to either import a header (it can be in multiple places) where it is defined. You *can* forward declare a struct if you do not need to access its properties, but that is the extent of it.

Comment: I do apologise (need to learn how to use google :P) - editing answer now. Is my answer now correct?

Comment: getting there -- it's more complicated than that.