# iOS: forward declaration of non objects type class

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, uiviewcontroller

I have property of type CLLocationCoordinate2D, how can I use forward declaration to declare that?

```
 @class CLLocationCoordinate2D;
```

do not works

Comment: You can't, just #import the header it's in.

Comment: add `@import CoreLocation;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for here is not forward declaration at all. You want to make use of the **struct** `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. First off that is not a class - for forward declaring structs look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120525/forward-declare-a-struct-in-objective-c).

**BUT** in your case you do not even have to use forward declaration since you only need to / have to include the correct header in your project. Namely CoreLocation:

```
@import CoreLocation;
```

or a little bit old fashioned

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Additionally you probably have to add the CoreLocation framework as well if you have not done that already.